# Default daily quota is set to 0 - how to upgrade it?

Tags: youtube-data-api, quota

We recently added YouTube data api to our project and realized that the account daily api quota is 0. Surprisingly when I created a new project/set of credentials, the quota is set to 10000. Could this be because the first account is older and something changed in the recent years?

To clarify - the project is active, we asked for quota upgrade but got no response and the quota field is uneditable. When contacted google support, they asked to post a question as the support is provided here.

This all is unnecessarily confusing, is there an easy way to reset the quota to default value of 10000???